# Can't insert all data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

The title is not disclosing the whole thing for sure.
Right now I'm working on a Lab Software. Here, all the individual test names & their details are in a table (say name 'test_info') & all the bills generated for those tests are in another table (say name 'bill_info') & when it's time to insert the test reports I'm storing it in another table (say name 'rpt_info').

There are a few group tests which are a collection of tests. I made a column named 'group' if the value is null then they are under no group test & when their is a value (which is name of a test) means this test is under that group test.

Now, take a look at what forced me to ask a question here.
When its time to enter the value of test report, I just call them like-

```
           <?php
          $gtsql = "SELECT * FROM `bill_info` where `test_id` = '" . $pid."' and `group`='y'";
        $reslt = mysql_query($gtsql);
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($reslt))
        {
            $test_inf=  "SELECT * FROM `test_info` where `group` = '". $data["pr_name"]."'";
            $test_qr=  mysql_query($test_inf);
             $k = 1;
             while ($test = mysql_fetch_assoc($test_qr)) {

            echo '<tr><td width="80"></td><td align="left"> <input name="name" id="name" style="border:none; background: transparent;" value="' .  $test["name"] . '" readonly/></td><td width="144" align="left"> <INPUT name="result" id="result" /></td><td width="125" align="left"><input name="unit" id="unit" style="border:none; background: transparent;" value="' . $test["unit"] . '" readonly/></td><td align="left">'; 
$ref= $test["ref_range"];
$ref2= $test["ref_range2"];
$ref3= $test["ref_range3"];
if($ref=!"")
{ echo '<br/><input name="ref_range" id="ref_range" style="border:none; background: transparent;" value="'.$test["ref_range"].'" readonly/>';} 
if ($ref2=!"")
{ echo '<br/><input name="ref_range2" id="ref_range2" style="border:none; background: transparent;" value="'.$test["ref_range2"].'" readonly/>';} else { echo "";}
if ($ref3=!"")
{ echo '<br/><input name="ref_range3" id="ref_range3" style="border:none; background: transparent;" value="'.$test["ref_range3"].'" readonly/>';} else { echo "";}; 

'
</td></tr>
';
            $k++;
             }
    }


         ?>
```

This is working fine & showing all the tests & their info perfectly on the screen to the user. But when I try to insert these data in 'rpt_info' table then the problem appears.
I've tried 'while', 'for' but can't insert the value to the table.
Here is the insert code that I am running right now. One more thing to share to you friends, to get the perfect number of tests I made a row in another table (name 'sell') where I put individual test (bill) records. the row named 'num'. I calculate the 'num' value to find out how many times I want to run the code. the `$num` comes perfect when I do echo that one. but every time I got only one row being inserted.

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['posted']))
  {

$prsql = "SELECT SUM(num) FROM `sell` where `test_id`='".$_POST['test_id']."'";
$prrs = mysql_query($prsql);
$datas = mysql_fetch_assoc($prrs);
$num= $datas['SUM(num)'];
$i=1;
while ($i < $num)
  {
$str_tst = "INSERT INTO `rpt_info` (`pt_id`,`test_id`,`result`,`name`,`unit`,`ref_range`, `ref_range2`, `ref_range3`, `rcv_date`, `dlv_date`, `age`, `test_cat`)VALUES ( '" . $_POST['pt_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['test_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['result'] . "', '" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['unit'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range2'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range3'] . "', '" . $_POST['rcv_date']. "', '" . $_POST['dlv_date'] . "', '" . $_POST['pt_age'] . "', '" .  $_POST['test_cat']. "')";

 $i++;

  }
?>

<?php
   if(mysql_query($str_tst))
     {
        echo '................';
}
?>
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

This is my first question & may be I can't clear this to all of you. If you want to be more clear about the problem then feel free please to ask me questions.

Comment: there is no insert query in your code ?

Comment: Post the part that is not working, not the part that is working

Comment: You didn't post the `insert` query nor the error message

Comment: Sorry for that, I am updating my question

Comment: Apart from the fact that you **should not use mysql_* functions** any more (use mysqli or PDO, you are creating an insert query, but you are not executing it.

Comment: There is no `name="test_id"` in your generated output. Also, you are using the same input names for all rows. You need to generate unique names or use arrays.

Comment: same input names for all rows? how can I generate unique names or arrays, I've less knowledge on array. & It's a 'while inside another while' when I'm showing the data, but how can I get the same input name when I try to insert data?

Comment: to have $str_tst1, $str_tst2 etc you have to use ${$str_tst1.$i}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your `$num= $datas['SUM(num)'];` doesn't exist. Try

```
$prsql = "SELECT SUM(num) as SumNum FROM `sell` where `test_id`='".$_POST['test_id']."'";
```

And you can get it using `$num= $datas['SumNum'];`

2) `$str_tst` is a simple string, you don't tell it to execute the query. You execute it using `mysql_query($str_tst) or die mysql_error();`. Use

```
while ($i < $num)
  {
$str_tst = "INSERT INTO `rpt_info` (`pt_id`,`test_id`,`result`,`name`,`unit`,`ref_range`, `ref_range2`, `ref_range3`, `rcv_date`, `dlv_date`, `age`, `test_cat`)VALUES ( '" . $_POST['pt_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['test_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['result'] . "', '" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['unit'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range2'] . "', '" . $_POST['ref_range3'] . "', '" . $_POST['rcv_date']. "', '" . $_POST['dlv_date'] . "', '" . $_POST['pt_age'] . "', '" .  $_POST['test_cat']. "')";
mysql_query($str_tst) or die mysql_error(); // Each loop execute the query
 $i++;

  }
```

3) Your `while` loop isn't correct. I think you're missing one insert. You begin to 1 and you go, for example, to 10, so you are inserting 9 rows BECAUSE you're using `<` instead of `<=`

Advice : Stop using mysql_*. Please change to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: 1) but when I do echo $num it is showing the right value :/
Ok, I'm trying your way now

Comment: The most important is that you are not executing your insert query, so this shouldn't work... And be careful, you are missing one insert. `$i` should begins to 0 or put `<=` in your loop

Comment: Use ` or die mysql_error()` at the end of your query to see what erroor you have

Comment: 3) I got that thought,too. But sadly every time it is inserting only 1 row, whether it is 5 or 6...

Comment: Look your loop. You get a string, then $i++, then THE SAME VAR is edited with the new query, then it is edeting it again ang again 5-6 times. I said you sould pu the insert IN the loop, not outside

Comment: What you do, for example is : $str_tst = "test1" then $str_tst = "test2" then $str_tst = "test3" and so on. At the end you have $str_tst = "test6" and you are inserting $str_tst which is test6, not test1 to test6. Do you understand ?

Comment: Cool, tag it as answered now :)